# rails has_many :through relationship query returns nothing, though records are saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm testing out some code in the Rails (v 6.0 if that matters) console, and having difficulty properly querying records that have a has_many :through relationship with each other. This makes me think I've setup my models incorrectly.

Here are my models:

**subscriber.rb**

```
has_many :subscriber_rewards, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :rewards, through: :subscriber_rewards
```

**reward.rb**

```
has_many :subscriber_rewards
has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriber_rewards
```

**subscriber_reward.rb**

```
belongs_to :reward
belongs_to :subscriber
```

I run this code in the console to create a new SubscriberReward assigned to a subscriber:

```
SubscriberReward.create(reward_id: 3, subscriber_id: 73)
```

But when I query the rewards of that subscriber...

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.find(73)
@subscriber.rewards
```

The console returns this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

When I would expect it to return an array of rewards associated with that subscriber through the just created SubscriberReward.

And if I look in the database for the last SubscriberReward, I see that it exists and appears to be assigned to the correct subscriber and reward.

```
SubscriberReward.last
=> #<SubscriberReward id: 3, reward_id: 3, subscriber_id: 73, created_at: "2020-11-15 19:42:58", updated_at: "2020-11-15 19:42:58">
```

Any idea why I can't just run @subscriber.rewards to access the rewards array that corresponds to that subscriber?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Formatting error excluded a line from my subscriber model

Comment: Does your model Subscriber has a relation `has_many :subscriber_rewards` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Formatting error on my part.

Comment: No problem. For me you models are rights. Do you execute your `@subscriber = Subscriber.find(73)` line after your `SubscriberReward.create(reward_id: 3, subscriber_id: 73)`
Can you put here your SQL after each lines?

Comment: What do you get if you do `@subscriber.subscriber_rewards`? What do you get if do something like `Reward.find(3).subscribers`? your code looks fine, maybe you have problems elsewhere, I think you need to show more code from your models.

Comment: Your models seem correct. What is the output of `@subscriber.subscriber_rewards.to_sql`?